# How to touch select a 3D object using Opengl ES 2.0 on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

How can i touch select a 3D object in the scene which is drawn using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android 6.0. I am using Min3D for Parsing the .3DS file and loaded to Android View using OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLSurfaceView class. I am able to load the 3D model; but i have no idea how to select each part of the 3D object using mouse click/touch.

For ex : I have a 3D model of car, and i need to touch select each part of the car, say doors; and change its colors/texture.

Suggest if there is much more easier way to do the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this.

Method 1: Draw all objects using different colours.In our case, we used the object id in the RGB values and rendered the image to a texture. Then you can read the pixel colour where the user is touching. The colour of pixel gives you the object id.

Method 2: Using Ray Hit Test on all bounding boxes of objects.

Method 1 is more reliable if you are looking for accuracy. Method 2 is faster but will not work in all cases. Especially when objects with overlapping bounding boxes.